# Xamarin.Forms - Should My Main Application File Be Named "App.cs" or "{name_of_project}.cs"?

Tags: xamarin, filenames, xamarin.forms, program-entry-point

Is there a convention around this? I think it would be better to name it App.cs, so that for any given project, you know exactly what file to look for.

Comment: They use to name it App.cs and recently changed it to use the name of the project. I agree with you though, that `App.cs` makes more sense to me.

Comment: Ok, that make sense. I was wondering, because the Xamarin docs were using App.cs, but when creating a new project in Visual Studio, it set it as the name of the project.

Answer (score 0):

the name is irelevant you will still cal the Base App.Current for the app instance if you need it like for Properties or somthing else

Comment: Small thing, but it's relevant when I'm in my Solution looking for the main app file. If it's always App.cs, it's easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your class does not matter at all. It's just a default value which is easy to find. I leave it like this, so I know inside the project where to change App-specific things.